# Generic Methods which can construct the Generic Type

Tags: java, generics

I'm adding Test Cases to a Test Suite as follows:

```
for(String methodName : getPublicDeclaredMethods(TestA.class))
{
    this.addTest((new TestA(methodName)));
}

for(String methodName : getPublicDeclaredMethods(TestB.class))
{
    this.addTest((new TestB(methodName)));
}
```

This is equivalent to doing this:

```
this.addTest((new TestA("TEST_METHOD_1")));
this.addTest((new TestA("TEST_METHOD_2")));
this.addTest((new TestB("TEST_METHOD_1")));
this.addTest((new TestB("TEST_METHOD_3")));  // woops I forgot TEST_METHOD_2
```

I'm stuck with this weird Test Framework where methods names are supplied as strings via construction.

My code above guarantees that I add all the Test Cases defined in a particular class. However, I'd like to have a method which looks something like this instead:

```
void <T> addTestCasesFromClass()
{
    for(String methodName : getPublicDeclaredMethods(T.class))
    {
        this.addTest((new T(methodName)));
    }
}
```

But I'm not sure how this is done in Java. Is it even possible? TestA and TestB are derived from the class Test.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generics are useless here, since you cannot do something like `new T`. But you can do it with some more reflection. Given that all classes you pass to this method are having a constructor which accepts exactly one String argument.

```
void addTestCasesFromClass(Class<?> clz)
{
     for(String methodName : getPublicDeclaredMethods(clz))
     { 
         this.addTest(clz.getConstructor(String.class).newInstance(methodName));
     }
}
```

A call would then look something like this

```
addTestCasesFromClass(TestA.class); 
addTestCasesFromClass(TestB.class);
```

If your `addTest` methods accepts only objects of a certain base class (let it be `TestBase`), then change the generic parameter of `clz` to `Class<? extends TestBase> clz`.

Comment: Am I right in saying that this method throws IllegalArgumentException, SecurityException, InstantiationException, IllegalAccessException, InvocationTargetException, NoSuchMethodException?

Comment: Sounds right, I left exception handling out for brevity reasons. Also I don't know how you want handle exceptions (if e.g. `clz` does not provide a accessible constructor which accepts a string).

Answer (score 1):

You are not able to instantiate when you only have a reference to a Generic type.
Generics are only available at compile time thus you can't use them while in runtime.
This means you will need a reference to the actual class Class and instantiate it trough reflection.

```
Class<?> clazz = ...
Object instance = clazz.newInstance();
```

*It's encouraged to use getConstructor instead though.*

A good example of this is the List.toArray method in java, it requires you to pass an instance of the array so it is able to have an actually reference to the Class, since generics are not available at runtime.

Answer (score 1):

You can use reflection to find the constructor of the class you are passed that accepts a string argument. Then instantiate your class using the method name you retrieve.

```
public <T> void addTestClassesFromClass(T item){
    try {
        Constructor<?> constructor = item.getClass().getConstructor(String.class);
        for(String methodName : getPublicDeclaredMethods(item.getClass())){
            this.addTest((constructor.newInstance(methodName)));
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("Oh crap!");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is my attempt:

```
public void addTestCasesFromClass(Class<? extends Test> c) throws IllegalArgumentException, SecurityException, InstantiationException, IllegalAccessException, InvocationTargetException, NoSuchMethodException
{
    for(String methodName : getPublicDeclaredMethods(c))
    {
        this.addTest((c.getDeclaredConstructor(String.class).newInstance(methodName)));
    }
}
```